# Properties of RDF subjects

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I have an nt file with three tubles subject, predicate, object
Now I want to group for each subject on its predicates. For example if I have

```
<s> <p1> <o1>
 <s> <p2> <o2>
 <s> <p3> <o3>
```

Then the output will be
s p1, p2, p3

using python rdflib
any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: `select (str(?s) as ?s_) (group_concat(distinct str(?p); separator=', ') as ?p_) { ?s ?p [] } group by ?s`?

Comment: thanks  Stanislav Kralin . Is this SPARQL or code can be written in Python

Comment: This is a SPARQL query. And you can execute this query with `rdflib`. documentation how to use SPARQL in `rdflib` is online

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SPARQL.  I want to create  csv file which contains all predicates for a given subject from rdf file format. The above query gave me subjects only with type predicates.